# MongoDB - Mongoose $inc an object inside of an array of a document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

So I am trying to update the value of an object inside an array inside a document. The Schema for the document looks like this:

```
var pollSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  hash: String,
  answers: [{answer: String, votes: Number}]
});
```

And this is how my current update code looks like:

```
module.exports.updatePoll = function(socket, data){
  var answerss = 'answers.0.votes';

  hash = data.url.match(/\/([^/]*)$/)[1];
  Poll.findOne({'hash' : hash}, function(err, poll){
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log(poll.answers[data.id])
  });
  Poll.update({hash: hash}, {$inc: {'answers.{data.id}.votes': 1}}, function(err, poll){
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    //socket.emit('updatePoll', hash);
  });
```

Ive tried pasting `answerss` in it instead of `'answers.{data.id}.votes'`and also tried some other things. It only really works when I directly paste in 'answers.0.votes'. And this is a problem because the `data.id` can be a value of 0 to 10. I have no idea how I would implement this and the other answers on stackoverflow or google did not give much insight on the problem.

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the initial find from what I can tell.  You can do it all in one update statement.  You need to match the array element you want to update simply by specifying its index:

```
      var answerKey = 'answers.' + data.id + '.votes';
  var updateJSON = {$inc: {}};
  updateJSON.$inc[answerKey] = 1;
  hash = data.url.match(/\/([^/]*)$/)[1];
  Poll.update({hash: hash}, updateJSON, function(err, poll){
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    //socket.emit('updatePoll', hash);
  });
```

Comment: ah thanks, but the answers.answer is a string not a number, the number is the answers[data.id]. So All i would need is the answer value?

Comment: that should make absolutely no difference assuming that data.id matches the value of answers.answer of the array element you want to increment.

Comment: But it doesnt, answers.answer would be something like: 'this is an answer'. And data.id would be 0 because its the first answer. For the second answer it would be 1 and the answers.answer would be: 'this is an second answer'

Comment: If that's the case you can just specify the index within your $inc statement.  Updated answer

Comment: Next time please test it first before posting. You should have known that would create an error. If you still need to know what error: Unexpected token +

Comment: Yeah like I said, please test before posting. You should know that doesnt work too.... Ive already explained i tried to do that.